# How to toggle class and get selected object on ember-models-table

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm working on a project that is using ember-models-table.

I cannot figure out to select a row and how to retrieve the data from the selected row into a function so I can work with it.

I've looked through all the [documentation](https://onechiporenko.github.io/ember-models-table/v.2/), but I cannot find anything related.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should check [this](https://onechiporenko.github.io/ember-models-table/v.2/#/examples/select-rows-with-checkboxes) part of documentation. I hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks! It didn't help much as I'm still trying to understand how ember works, and couldn't figure much from there. But hey, thank you.